# How to hide div on outside click except one inside div through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is just a sample code where i want hide div with id="img" on button click as well as outside div with with id="img"

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img">
<button id"imgoption"> click here</butoon>
</div>
```

Here os the Script

```
<script>
 $(document).on('click', function(e) { // Hides the div by clicking any where in the screen

      if ( ! $(e.target).closest('#img').length ){
            $('#imgoption').hide();
        }
        if ( $(e.target).closest('#img').length ) {
              $("#imgoption").show();
        }

    });
}):
</script>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear for me, what is expected result? what is current result?

Comment: <div id="img">Name
<button id"imgoption"> click here</butoon>
</div>
I want when i click on button it close will close main #img and also when i click outside from #img it will close the.
Till now everything is working except button click is not hiding #img because butoon is inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mouseup`  for this purpose.

```js
 $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $("#img");
  var con = $("#imgoption");
if (!container.is(e.target))
  container.hide();
if (con.is(e.target))
  container.parents().hide();
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img">
  <button id "imgoption"> click here</butoon>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you use relative selectors like `.parent()` or `.parents()` in order to traverse your dom from the `$("imgoption")` click event.

```js
$("#imgoption").click(function () {
  $(this).parents("#img").hide();
  //you can technically do $(this).parent().hide(), but if you add more dom, the former is more bullet proof.
})
```

```css
div#img {
  padding:40px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- NOTE: I did fix typos from your example -->
<div id="img">
    <button id="imgoption"> click here</button>
</div>
```

Disclaimer:  If this isn't what you meant, just leave a comment.

Comment: Not same but in adddition with this i want whenever i click outside the blue color area or #img it will hide #img

Comment: Is that what you meant?  I added new snippet into the post.  Additionally, I did add sample image.  You have no reason to have two separate click events if one of the click-ables is nested inside the other.

Comment: I found my answer above. Go through it...Thank You

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
<script>
 $(document).on('click', function(e) {

      if ( ! $(e.target).closest('#img').length ){
            $('#img').hide();
            //or
            $('#img').parent().hide();
        }
        if ( $(e.target).closest('#img').length ) {
              $("#img").show();
              //or
              $('#img').parent().show();
        }

    });
}):
</script>
```